# Geometric probability. On the interval [0, 5] we randomly and independently choose two numbers that divide this interval into three sections

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

On the interval [0, 5] we randomly and independently choose two numbers that divide this interval into three sections. The smaller number is denoted by a and the larger number by b. What is the probability event that section [a, b] will be the shortest and section [0, a] the longest?

I tried to solve this problem many times and I still can't figure out the correct way to do it.

Comment: Make a plot with axes $a$ and $b$ and color the resulting plane by your test condition.  The answer will then be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the two numbers, with $a=max(x,y)$ $b=min(x,y)$.

Let $E$ be the event of interest.

Notice first that $P(E| x>y) = P(E| x<y) $, by symmetry, hence $P(E)=P(E| x>y)$. Let's compute $P(E| x>y)$; then, we assume that $x>y$, hence $b=x$ and $a=y$.

The conditions on the three lengths can be written as $b-a< 5-b < a$.

That is, $y>2x-5$ and $y>5-x$

Those inequalities corresponds to a region on the $x-y$ plane. Because the condition dictates that the points are uniform inside a triangle $0<y<x<5$, we only need to intersect that with the above requirements, and compute the relative area.

Can you go on from here?